# Physics behind breaking

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, material-science, free-body-diagram

A very simple query.

Suppose a box rests on a frictionless table. It has a max. normal force of $100 N$, say. Suppose I exert a force of $150 N$, which I suppose is not possible, since normal force by me and  the box are $3rd$ law pairs. This leads to my question $-$

How do we break stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we place a box with a weight of $150$ N on a table that can support a maximum load of $100$ N. There are two action-reaction pairs here. In the first pair the Earth exerts a downward force of $150$ N on the box, and the box in turn exerts an upward force on $150$ N on the Earth (we usually ignore the second force in this pair because it is not going to the move the Earth by any measurable amount). In the second pair the table exerts an upward force of $100$ N on the box and the box exerts a downward force of $100$ N on the table. We could go on and analyse the forces between the table and the Earth, but we will ignore those for now.

If you look at the forces on the box you see that there is a downward force of $150$ N from the Earth (its weight) and an upward force of $100$ N from the table (the normal force). So the box is not in equilibrium - there is a net downwards force of $50$ N on it, and so it will accelerate downwards. Its mass is $150/g$ kg, so it will accelerate downwards at a rate of $g/3$. The table will deform and will eventually break - how much the table can deform before it breaks depends on what it is made out of.

Contrast this with the scenario where we place the box in a tank of water, and the volume of the box is such that the maximum buoyancy force from  the water (when the box is totally submerged) is $100$ N. Once again, the box will accelerate downwards at a rate of $g/3$ (i.e. it sinks), but now the water flows around it and fills in the space above it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete answer, but to give a few keywords for further exploration. We are talking here about [*deformations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(engineering)), so even our departing point should be not simply a box on a table, but a table deformed under the weight of the box:

- As long as, after removing the box, the table returns to its initial position, we are talking about an *elastic deformation*.
- It might be that the table does not return to its initial position. This situation is perhaps not very common with a table, but if we think abouyt a heavy object that was laying on the top of carbord, it will likely leave a trace. In this case the deformation is called *plastic deformation*.
- Finally, when the table cracks under the weight of the box, we call it *fructure*.

The basic relationship between the force (stress) and the displacement of the object (strain) is illustrated in [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deformation_(engineering)#/media/File:Stress-strain1.svg)

Comment: Not exactly my question. I am asking when it breaks, what are the action reaction pairs?

Comment: What I am saying is that you cannot consider the table and the box as material points in this case (which is the basis of newtonian mechanics), and treat them as continuous media. So for matematical treatment you will need partial differential equations, which are studied in elasticity theory. And even there plasticity and fraction are rather advanced subjects. I could look up a few textbooks, but you can also use the keywords that I mentioned to find more materials on your preferred level.

Answer (score 1):

If the box is a completely theoretical object, which cannot be deformed and can hold on to infinite stress, you cannot exert that kind of force.

However, if the box is deformable, the force you exert squeezes the material in a way that the atoms inside the material are pushed close to each other. Your $3rd$ law pairs are now between the atoms.

At some point, you give enough energy to break the bonds that is holding the atoms together, and you break the box.

***This explanation is extremely simplified version of what really happens in real materials.***

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. 100N is maximal force without breaking. If you apply more, table breaks and the broken parts start to accelerate due the applied force. According to the third Newton law, accelerating object resist attempts at accelerating them by the reaction force and broken, accelerating parts will produce equivalent reaction force.